# HTML elements move when I zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with my website, I mean when I zoom in, the logo image and the vision image moves, even the container which contains the description moves and the date also moves to the left as shown in the figure below:
[image]

I don't want the elements to move when I zoom in or out. I want the elements to be in the same position how can I do that?

here my HTML code:

```css
body
{
 background-color:#F6F2F2; 
 font-family: Calibri;
 background-size:cover;
}
hr
{
  opacity: 25%;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    border-color: #ffffff;   
}
.square
{
height: 100px;
width: 120px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
margin-right: 900px;
}
.square_section
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: -98px;   
}
.square_events
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-top: -98px;    
}
.square_adv
{
   height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-top: -98px;
}
.square_user
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-top: -98px;   
}
.square_vision
{
    border-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -398px;
    margin-top: -100px;  
}

.vl {
    border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    opacity: 10px;
  }

@media (min-width: 992px){
    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle:after{
      border-top: .3em solid transparent;
        border-right: .3em solid;
        border-bottom: .3em solid transparent;
    }

    .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu{
      margin-left:0; margin-right: 0;
      direction: rtl;   
    }

    .nav-link
    {
      margin-top: -22px; 
      direction: rtl; 
    }

    .dropdown-menu li{
      position: relative;
      direction: rtl; 
    }
    .nav-item .submenu{ 
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      right:100%; top:-7px;
    }
    .nav-item .submenu-left{ 
      right:100%; left:auto;
       
    }

    .dropdown-menu > li:hover{ background-color: #f1f1f1;
         
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li:hover > .submenu{
      display: block;
      direction: rtl; 
    }
  }     
.btn
{
    direction: rtl;  
    margin-left: -95px !important;
    margin-right: -80px;
    margin-bottom: -80px; 
    margin-top: -11px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
    color: black;
}
#logout
{
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 14px;
}
#sections
{
margin-left: 44px;
margin-top: 10px;  
}
#mes_logout
{
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
#user_welcome
{
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 14px; 
}
#mes_welcome
{
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px; 
}
#vision_img
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: 3px; 
    margin-left: 25px;   
}
#logo_img
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -100px;  
}
#events
{
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#description_img
{
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 860px !important;
}
#section_img_list
{
  margin-left: 790px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#text_sections
{
text-align: right;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: -30px;
margin-right: 70px;
}
#calnder_img
{
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#date_message
{
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color:black;
  width: 100%;   
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.quotes {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -150px;
  color: black;
}
.rectangle {
  height: 190px;
  width: 850px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 190px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.rectangle_second
{
  height: 190px;
  width: 850px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 190px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.footer {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 20%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color:#002060;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -375px;
  padding: 6px;
}
.date_time
{
  height: 220px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 1100px;
  margin-top: -600px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.date
{
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #002060;      
}
.movie-img {
    height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
#quaality_img
{
  height:110px;width: 110px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 20px; 
}
#relations_img
{
  height:110px;width: 110px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#quaality_msg
{
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;     
}
#user_adv
{
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#mes_adv
{
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon 
{
  background-color: #1F419E;
  color: #1F419E;
  transform: translateX(33.333%);
}
.carousel-control-next-icon 
{
  background-color: #1F419E;
  color: #1F419E;
  margin-left:38px; 
}
.movie-img1
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 155px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img2
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 280px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img3
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img4
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 530px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img5
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 660px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img6
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img7
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 155px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img8
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 280px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img9
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img10
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 530px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}
.movie-img11
{
  height:100px;width: 100px;background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
  margin-right: 660px;
  margin-top: -99px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  opacity: 200%;
  box-shadow: #e2e2e2;
}    
#book_img
{
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#day
{
  color: #002060;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 25px;      
}
#months
{
  color: #002060;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
}
#year
{
  color: #002060;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
}
.time
{
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #002060;
  margin-left: 1100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white; 
}
#clock
{
  text-align: center;
 margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:112%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  
}
#library_img
{
  margin-right: 20px;
  
}
#library_msg
{
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#trainee_img
{
  margin-right: 25px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}
#trainee_msg
{
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#it_img
{
  margin-right: 25px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}
#it_msg
{
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 12px;
}  
.position
{
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: -90px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
        <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script> -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <title>home</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
              var quotes = $(".quotes");
              var quoteIndex = -1;
              function showNextQuote() {
                  ++quoteIndex;
                  quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
                          .fadeIn(1090)
                          .delay(1090)
                          .fadeOut(1090, showNextQuote);
              }
              showNextQuote();
          })();
      </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // jQuery code
              $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
              });
              if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                    if($(this).next('.submenu').length){
                      $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
                    }
                    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
                   $(this).find('.submenu').hide();
                })
                });
            }   
          }); // jquery end   
    </script>     
      </head>
      <body>  
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-light bg-light">   <!-- start navbar -->
            <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- start div container-fluid-->
              <img id="img" src="img/image.png" alt="img">
                <div class="position">
              <div class="square">
                <img id="logout" src="img/logout.png" alt="logout">
                <p id="mes_logout"> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="square_section"> <!-- start div square section-->
                <img id="sections" src="img/sections.png" alt="sections">
                <div class="btn-group">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">    </a>
                       <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
       <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
                        
                     </ul>
                    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">       </a>
                       <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href=""> </a></li>
                     </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">     </a>
                       <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
                     </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">  </a>
                      <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
             <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
                    </ul>
                   </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="square_user">
                <img id="user_welcome" src="img/user (1).png" alt="logout">
                <p id="mes_welcome"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="square_vision">
              <img id="vision_img" src="img/Saudi_Vision_2030_logo.svg.png" alt="logout">
            </div>
            <div class="vl"></div>
           <img id="logo_img" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"> 
            </div> 
          </nav>  
          <div class="container">
            <img id="description_img" src="img/Capture.png" alt="Snow" style="width:80%;">
            <div class="centered">
                  <h5 class="quotes">
                  </h5>
                  <h5 class="quotes">
                  </h5>
                  <h5 class="quotes">
                  </h5>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rectangle">
           <img id ="section_img_list" src="img/section.png" alt="section">
           <p id="text_sections"></p>
           <hr>
           <div dir="rtl" class="row mx-auto my-auto"> <!--  start div carousel --> 
           <div dir="rtl" id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">  <!--  start div carousel --> 
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="movie-card m-1"> 
                  <div class="movie-img">
                    <a id="quaality_img" href="#"><img src="img/quality-assurance.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img1">
                    <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/relations.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">     </p>
                  </div> 
                  <div class="movie-img2">
                    <a id="quaality_img" href="#"><img src="img/customer-service.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img3">
                    <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/books-stack-of-three.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">     </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img4">
                    <a id="it_img" href="#"><img src="img/data.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="it_msg">   </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img5">
                    <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/briefcase.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="movie-card m-1"> 
                    <div class="movie-img">
                      <a id="quaality_img" href="#"><img src="img/quality-assurance.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="movie-img1">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/relations.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">     </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img2">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/call-center-agent.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img3">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/student-in-the-library.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">   </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img4">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/boss.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg"> </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img5">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/debt.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg"> </p>
                    </div>       
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="movie-img6">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/briefcase.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img7">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/gift.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                </div>

                <div class="movie-img8">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/homework.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img9">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/parchment.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">   </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img10">
                  <a id="library_img" href="#"><img src="img/library.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="library_msg">  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img11">
                  <a id="trainee_img" href="#"><img src="img/presentation.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="trainee_msg"> </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel"  data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next " type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel"  data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div> 
        </div>  
        </div> 
           <div class="rectangle_second"> 
            <img id ="section_img_list" src="img/advertising.png" alt="section">
           <p id="text_sections"></p>
           <hr>
           <div dir="rtl" class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div dir="rtl" id="recipeCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false"> 
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="movie-card m-1"> 
                      <div class="movie-img">
                        <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/data.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                        <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="movie-card m-1">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel1"  data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next " type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel1"  data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
           </div>
           </div> 
           <div class="footer">
           </div>
          <div class="date_time">
            <div class="date">
              <img id="calnder_img" src="img/calenda.png" alt="calnder">
              <p id="date_message"></p>
              <p id="day"></p>
              <p id="months"></p>
              <p id="year"></p>
            </div>
           </div> 
           <div class="time">
            <p id="clock"></p>
          </div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put it inside a wrap, and it worked:

HTML:

```html
<html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
        <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script> -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <title>home</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
              var quotes = $(".quotes");
              var quoteIndex = -1;
              function showNextQuote() {
                  ++quoteIndex;
                  quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
                          .fadeIn(1090)
                          .delay(1090)
                          .fadeOut(1090, showNextQuote);
              }
              showNextQuote();
          })();
      </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // jQuery code
              $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
              });
              if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                    if($(this).next('.submenu').length){
                      $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
                    }
                    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
                   $(this).find('.submenu').hide();
                })
                });
            }   
          }); // jquery end   
    </script>     
      </head>
      <body> 
      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-light bg-light">   <!-- start navbar -->
            <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- start div container-fluid-->
              <img id="img" src="img/image.png" alt="img">
                <div class="position">
              <div class="square">
                <img id="logout" src="img/logout.png" alt="logout">
                <p id="mes_logout"> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="square_section"> <!-- start div square section-->
                <img id="sections" src="img/sections.png" alt="sections">
                <div class="btn-group">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">    </a>
                       <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
       <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
                        
                     </ul>
                    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">       </a>
                       <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href=""> </a></li>
                     </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">     </a>
                       <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">   </a></li>
                     </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">  </a>
                      <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
             <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">  </a></li>
                    </ul>
                   </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="square_user">
                <img id="user_welcome" src="img/user (1).png" alt="logout">
                <p id="mes_welcome"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="square_vision">
              <img id="vision_img" src="img/Saudi_Vision_2030_logo.svg.png" alt="logout">
            </div>
            <div class="vl"></div>
           <img id="logo_img" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"> 
            </div> 
          </nav>  
          </header>
          <div id="wrap">
          <div class="container">
            <img id="description_img" src="img/Capture.png" alt="Snow" style="width:80%;">
            <div class="centered">
                  <h5 class="quotes">
                  </h5>
                  <h5 class="quotes">
                  </h5>
                  <h5 class="quotes">
                  </h5>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rectangle">
           <img id ="section_img_list" src="img/section.png" alt="section">
           <p id="text_sections"></p>
           <hr>
           <div dir="rtl" class="row mx-auto my-auto"> <!--  start div carousel --> 
           <div dir="rtl" id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">  <!--  start div carousel --> 
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="movie-card m-1"> 
                  <div class="movie-img">
                    <a id="quaality_img" href="#"><img src="img/quality-assurance.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img1">
                    <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/relations.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">     </p>
                  </div> 
                  <div class="movie-img2">
                    <a id="quaality_img" href="#"><img src="img/customer-service.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img3">
                    <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/books-stack-of-three.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">     </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img4">
                    <a id="it_img" href="#"><img src="img/data.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="it_msg">   </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="movie-img5">
                    <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/briefcase.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                  <div class="movie-card m-1"> 
                    <div class="movie-img">
                      <a id="quaality_img" href="#"><img src="img/quality-assurance.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="movie-img1">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/relations.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">     </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img2">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/call-center-agent.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img3">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/student-in-the-library.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg">   </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img4">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/boss.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg"> </p>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="movie-img5">
                      <a id="relations_img" href="#"><img src="img/debt.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                      <p id="quaality_msg"> </p>
                    </div>       
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="movie-img6">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/briefcase.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img7">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/gift.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                </div>

                <div class="movie-img8">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/homework.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img9">
                  <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/parchment.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="quaality_msg">   </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img10">
                  <a id="library_img" href="#"><img src="img/library.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="library_msg">  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-img11">
                  <a id="trainee_img" href="#"><img src="img/presentation.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <p id="trainee_msg"> </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel"  data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next " type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel"  data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div> 
        </div>  
        </div> 
           <div class="rectangle_second"> 
            <img id ="section_img_list" src="img/advertising.png" alt="section">
           <p id="text_sections"></p>
           <hr>
           <div dir="rtl" class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div dir="rtl" id="recipeCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false"> 
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="movie-card m-1"> 
                      <div class="movie-img">
                        <a id="book_img" href="#"><img src="img/data.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                        <p id="quaality_msg">  </p>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="movie-card m-1">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel1"  data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next " type="button" data-bs-target="#recipeCarousel1"  data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
           </div>
           </div> 
           <div class="footer">
           </div>
          <div class="date_time">
            <div class="date">
              <img id="calnder_img" src="img/calenda.png" alt="calnder">
              <p id="date_message"></p>
              <p id="day"></p>
              <p id="months"></p>
              <p id="year"></p>
            </div>
           </div> 
           <div class="time">
            <p id="clock"></p>
          </div>
          </div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```css
#wrap{
    width:1325px;
}
```